# Windows 10 Планировать задачи через командную строку: параметр [<пароль>]

Tags: windows, cmd

Параметр программы schtasks "[пароль]"

[<пароль>] - пароль для указанного пользовательского контекста. Запрос ввода, если не указан.

Вопрос.

[<пароль>] - этот пароль соответствует системому паролю которая используется для входа в систему ? или этот пароль установливается для запланированную задачу ?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ:

Да, этот пароль соответствует системому паролю который используется для входа в систему.

То есть, попросту говоря, это пароль пользовтеля, от имени которго в системе будет запущена задача.

Как ни странно, про многие параметры командной строки для запуска  задач можно узнать, зайдя в UI   task sheduler'а.